# array, replace objects with correct index, algorithm

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have array with objects, I need replace objects with correct index
[image]

Comment: You have an NSArray? Your question doesn't make sense. An NSArray is 1D. Please explain better and show as much about the issue as possible.

Comment: yes,I have array with objects, I need sort array as show on the image

Answer (score 0):

Target objects: **29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34**

1. get objects to move and retain.
2. removeObjectAtIndex:
3. insertObject:atIndex:
4. release temp object

Comment: hi, the algorithm is important, detail implementation of code, you gotta try. count of array can change, but you know which index to insert the objects right?

Comment: Good, let me know if you encounter other problems.